# xslt select a node value based on the value of another node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am being tasked with creating a csv file using XSLT to produce the information. So far I have almost everything that I need however, there is one bit that i am struggling to get as per the example below.

```
<issuesExport xmlns="http://www.mynamesapce.co.uk/import">
<materials>
<material>
  <code>WB821</code>
  <name>CONCENTRATE</name>
</material>
<material>
  <code>WB820</code>
  <name>ADDITIVE</name>
</material>
</materials>
<issues>
 <issue>
  <formulaCode>TEST</formulaCode>
  <materialBatch>
    <materialCode>WB821</materialCode>
    <batchNumber>sdfsd</batchNumber>
    <isManualAddBatch>false</isManualAddBatch>
    <isFinished>true</isFinished>
    <weight>0</weight>
    <cost>0</cost>
  </materialBatch>
  <issueBatchNumber>df34323</issueBatchNumber>
</issue>
```

What I need to do is to grab the name from //material/name where issue/materialBatch/materialCode = material/code.

my current XSLT looks like this

```
<xsl:if test="i:materialBatch/i:materialCode=//i:material/i:code">
  <xsl:value-of select="//i:materials/i:material/i:name"/>
</xsl:if>
```

Which is always evaluating to true and giving my a result of CONCENTRATE.

I would be grateful if someone could tell me where I am going wrong

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test always returns true, because you are comparing two node-sets - and such test returns true if one of the nodes in set A matches a node in set B.

The result is always "CONCENTRATE" because

```
<xsl:value-of select="//i:materials/i:material/i:name"/>
```

returns the value of the **first** node of the set matching the `select` expression.

XSLT has a [build-in mechanism for looking up referenced values](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key). In order to use it, start by defining a key at the top-level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:key name="material-bycode" match="i:material" use="i:code" />
```

Then, from the context of `issue` you can use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="key('material-by-code', i:materialBatch/i:materialCode)/i:name"/>
```

to retrieve the corresponding name.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<xsl:if test="i:materialBatch/i:materialCode=//i:material/i:code">
  <xsl:value-of select="//i:materials/i:material/i:name"/>
</xsl:if>
```

To:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/i:issuesExport/i:materials/i:material[i:code = i:materialBatch/i:materialCode]/i:name"/>
```

Also note that `//` searches the complete XML document. Please try to avoid using `//` where ever you can to speed things up.